# Utterly confused how browserify & browserify-shim are supposed to work

Tags: jquery, browserify, browserify-shim

Well i started simple to grasp whats going on:
So I have one plugin which depends on jQuery, figure from there, i'd build on that and simply add more. However the only thing I can get to work is jQuery by itself.

This is the error I get from the terminal:

```
[13:24:27] { [Error: Cannot find module 'jquery.mixitup.js' from '/Users/antonioortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/browserify_app/app/_js']
```

Here is my setup:

package.json

```
"main": "./app/_js/app.js", //entry point for your app
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
        "browserify-shim", // Is this supposed to help with the non `node_module` pacakages?
         "debowerify"
    ]
},

"browser": { // This gives browserify the location of your plugin right?
    "mixitup": "./bower_components/mixitup/src/jquery.mixitup.js"
},

"browserify-shim": { 
    "jQuery": "global:jQuery",
    "mixitup": {
        "depends": "jQuery",
        "exports": "mixitup"

    }
```

On a basic level the `browserify-shim` is supposed to accomplish fetching non 'node_modules' right? Does anyone mind setting the record straight, because for the life of me I can't configure this correctly. But more importantly, I'd love to know what is going on!

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

So it appears if you use
    `var mixitup = require('./../bower_components/mixitup/build/jquery.mixitup.min.js');` in your `app.js` file it works. But then what is the point of the `browserify-shim`. I though it was supposed to allow you to use the shortened convention:

In my case, it would be:

```
var mixitup = require('jquery.mixitup.js');
```

**UPDATE**

Based on Nick's suggestions tried this, granted I didn't use proxyquireify. Anyone has another method. As I am still in the weeds...

```
"browser": {
        "jQuery": "global:jQuery",
        "mixitup": "/app/bower_components/mixitup/src/jquery.mixitup.js",
        "Mustache": "/app/bower_components/jquery-Mustache/jquery.mustache.js",
        "mustache": "mustache"
    }
```

But with no success...

[image: file path]

Also getting a error message which seems more cryptic then the last:

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, lstat '/app']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/app',
  stream:
```

Answer (score 0):

Browserify-shim makes allows you to export a module based on the mapping you provide. So in your example you should require your module via `mixitup` e.g. `var mixitup = require('mixitup');`. You are getting a module error because you are looking for a module called `jquery.mixitup.js`. More information on how node's module system works [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules).

You don't need the `exports` since browserify-shim exports the alias by default ([docs](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim#b-config-inside-packagejson-with-aliases)):

```
"mixitup": {
  "depends": "jQuery"
}
```

You also don't need to use `debowerify` if you are using `browserify-shim`.

Comment: Hey Nick, Did some searching and it appears `proxyquire` pertains to testing? So I suppose the rest of your recommendation requires implementing proxquire?

Comment: Great! Hey, in your experience, have you come across a good TUT which starts out with maybe `jQuery` and another plugin. Just so I can get frosty.
There is one on the `broserify` doc page, pertaining to `ember` but I am still a little green (obviously!) THANKS!